# ASP.NET User Control Inheriting from User Control Generates Null Reference

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, webusercontrol

This must be a common problem.

- User control A has a TextBox T.
- User control B inherits from user control A.
- User control B is placed onto page P.

During the Page_Load event of page P, if you attempt to access TextBox T, you'll find it's null.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: to quote the stack ad banner: "Do you haz teh codez?" (code please)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inheriting UserControls from UserControls is not a good strategy.  Elements in the parent UserControl will not be rendered - this is why your TextBox is null.

A better option would be to have UserControl A contained within UserControl B - this way elements of UserControl A can be reused across your other UserControls.

Have a look at this other post about inheriting UserControls - [How (if at all) can you make an ASP.NET UserControl inherit from another UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/638525/503969).

Answer (score 1):

Does control B's ASCX include textbox T? It needs to in order for textbox T to be not null. If controlB doesn't include textbox T, the property declared in the code behind isn't bound to any front end control and thus remains null.