# Is it possible to convert input control to label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a form that contains a lot of User Controls, each User Control is part of the form (contains TextBox, ComboBox etc).

User will use the form to update their information.
At end of submission, I need to display the original data and the data that the user have entered.

I wonder if is possible that I can replace the input control (TextBox etc) to Label?
So I can just simply use the same user control, then convert each of the input control to label to display the data... (I just don't really want to use readonly or disable)

Note: I used different dataset to map each of the User Control data....

What I was thinking to do is like to get the input control from Page.Controls:

```
aInputControl  = new Label();
```

or...

```
Page.Controls.Remove(aInputControl);
```

Then somehow add new Label in same position in the page... 
But I have no idea how...can't think of anything except add another div to surround each of the control...

I just wonder if it this is possible...

Thanks in advance.

================

Edit: Seems like making new user control is not a good way for me....I will just try to somehow map each original data and new data into a new User control, and write them into page...but anyway, thanks for the idea guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to rethink your design. I recommend you have another view/page that displays the data summary after submit. Additionally, you will have more control of the formatting this way. I don't want to sound condescending, but it just sounds like you are being a little lazy.

Comment: Because I have no idea what kind of input data is going to be need later on, I only got told that there will be much more questions and survey (like really many pages) to add into the forum, if I make another view page will take double of the work.  Also I want to be flexiable enough to customize the page by putting different user control.

Comment: Actually, years ago I created a survey app in ASP.NET WebForms and did exactly what you were asking for help with - except I just disabled the controls (you said you didnt want to do that). However, recently I decided to rewrite this app with MVC, and I found that it was much easier to just iterate through the questions and responses in a 'details' view as plain text than try to recycle the 'edit' view to display data. Trust me, it will make your life a LOT easier.

Comment: Actually I just did iterate through all the questions(user controls that contrains input controls), using their ID to find their original data and the data that user have just entered, then write them onto the page as HTML.  Thanks for sharing your experience~

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom user control that contains a TextBox and a Label, and displays one or the other depending on whether or not it has a value.

Comment: but I have been using some other company's component as all my input controls, TextBox, MaskedTextBox, ComboBox, DatePicker etc... I wonder if is possible that I can't inhert from their control...?

Comment: You should be able to inherit - check to see if the classes are sealed.

Comment: but from .... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638525/how-if-at-all-can-you-make-an-asp-net-usercontrol-inherit-from-another-usercont) it said cannot inhert from another user control..

Comment: Sorry - I didn't mean inherit from the UserControl.  I mean create a new user control that is composed of the other two controls (Object Composition).  Then, internal to that UserControl, you can toggle which one shows up.

Comment: I've done what skaz is talking about, by implementing a property that tracks the "mode" the page is in (view, edit, update, etc) and displays controls based on the mode.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a user control or a web control to encapsulate that functionality. Add a Property to change the display mode and some logic in the control to determine which control to show.

Here is a sample of code to give you an idea, I can expand on this if you would like.

```
public class ReadOnlyControl<T> : WebControl where T : Control, ITextControl {
    protected T inputControl;
    protected Label lblLabel;

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override void  Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        Control control = IsReadOnly ? lblLabel : (Control)inputControl;
        ((ITextControl)control).Text = Text;
        control.RenderControl(writer);
    }

}
```

Comment: hmm I wonder how this code will fits in my design.... so I will replace all my input control with ReadOnlyControl in my asp file? Kind of wonder how to write that <T> in asp file..

Comment: I can't recall how I did this before, but probably the easiest way to keep your syntax clean an easy is to subclass this class. ie `TextBoxReadOnly : ReadOnlyControl<TextBox>`